# Xamarin.Forms Navigate to another page using ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have several ContentPages and I want to navigate from one to another at the click of an element in the page. I have my ViewModel class:

```
 class JumpVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private INavigation _navigation;

        public ICommand NewPage
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    await _navigation.PushAsync(new MySettingsPage());
                });
            }
        }

        public JumpVM() { }

        public JumpVM(INavigation navitation)
        {
            _navigation = navitation;
        }
    }
```

And this is one of my pages( for the sake of space, i put only the relevant code):

```
BindingContext = new JumpVM(this.Navigation);
```

....

```
 Image fbInvite = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromResource(Constants.ASSETLOCATION + ".facebookInviteIcon.png"),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            fbInvite.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer(sender =>
                {
                    //navigation in the method below
                    FaceboonInviteFriends();
                    fbInvite.Opacity = 0.8;
                    fbInvite.FadeTo(1);
                }));
```

I want when I click the image, to execute the Command in the JumpVM class and navigate to the page there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line after the `FadeTo` line:
`((JumpVM)BindingContext).NewPage.Execute(null)`.

Comment: Actually, it does answer. I will add just a small hint to my answer.

Comment: Thank you :) That helped. I'm gonna mark as answered, but if you can help me with another thing related to this, would be nice. As you can see I've hard coded where it would jump " await _navigation.PushAsync(new MySettingsPage());" . But for more flexibility, can I put a certain page there depending on what button I click?

Comment: Sure, you can create any page you want and use it as a parameter.

Comment: Like BindingContext = new JumpVM(new MyNewPage(),this.Navigation);?

Answer (score 9):

This is Answer for Navigating one page to another page in ViewModel concept.

```
public ICommand NavigationList { get; set; }

NavigationList = new Command(GetListview);  

public void  GetListview()
{
   Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ListViewPerson());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ViewModels you can implement this easily with ICommand.

```
namespace YourApp.ViewModels
{
    public class CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        public ICommand BackToPage  {get; private set; }

        public CurrentPageViewModel()
        {
            BackToPage = new Command(async () => {
              await  Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And in the ViewModel of the page that you want to go, you need to implement the PopAsync as follows.

```
namespace YourApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel 
    {
        public ICommand BackToMain { get; private set; }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            BackToMain = new Command(async () => {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Also remember to use the Bindings at your Views CodeBehind on both the current page and that you want to go the like this.

```
namespace RealmApp1.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        }      
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you! 
Have A Nice Code!!!